# Python socket buffering and data loss

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, buffer

Working on a pet project to create a working mouse for my computer from an android device, I have a python server running on the PC and the android app sending it the data needed.

My idea for creating this mouse was to use Motion_Event UP and MOVE to record your finger movement on the device screen, calculate the difference between your last and new x,y coordinates and send the difference to the PC so it would move the mouse in the same pattern

Now I have a few problems from the sending itself to the calculation and I really wanted your guys opinions on how I should have done this better algorithm wise or just a bad implementation to the code on my part.

Java:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
        oldX = (int) event.getX();
        oldY = (int) event.getY();
    }
    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ){
        newX = (int) event.getX();
        newY = (int) event.getY();

        xDiff = newX - oldX;
        yDiff = newY - oldY;
        Log.v("xdiff", ""+xDiff);
        Log.v("ydiff", ""+yDiff);
        oldX = newX;
        oldY = newY;
        a.mouse(xDiff, yDiff);
    }
    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

    }
    return true;
}
```

sockets:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
    this.sock = new Socket("10.0.0.2", 9871);
    outToServer = new DataOutputStream(this.sock.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

        public void mouse(int x, int y) {

            try {

                this.outToServer.writeBytes(""+x+","+y);


            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

python sockets:

```
def __init__(self, IP, port):
    try:
        self.acceptor = socket.socket()
        self.acceptor.bind((IP, port)) 
        self.acceptor.listen(1)    
    except socket.error, e:
        print e

def start_server(self):
    try:
        print "serv up"
        self.sock, self.connecting_ip = self.acceptor.accept() 
        print self.connecting_ip[0] + " connected!"

    except socket.error, e:
        print e
```

the data handling itself:

```
def mouse(self):
    try:
        while True:
            data = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if data:
                coords = data.split(",")
                x = int(coords[0])
                y = int(coords[1])
                current_x = win32api.GetCursorPos()[0]
                current_y = win32apo.GetCursorPos()[1]
                win32api.SetCursorPos((current_x+x,current_y+y))
            else:
                self.sock.close()
    except socket.error, e:
        print e
```

The issues I get are:

1) Instead of getting the data like I sent it ("" + x + "," + y) it load waaay more data into the buffer and comes out as x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y...
I tried messing with the buffer size but that didn't do much
(note that the weird thing about this is I don't get this error when I'm running the app on my simulator and I get exactly what I want into the buffer which is x,y all separate from each other but when I run it on my android device(SGS2 if it at all matters) the data goes bunkers and sends everything all at once)

2) Another thing I get is data being "corrupted" or missing as in sending '' instead of a number or having 4 and -5 sent as 4-5 instead of 4,-5

All in all I'm pretty sure I've fucked up majorly here and I was hoping for someone to shed light on how should I go about doing this.

UDP Implement:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {

        this.clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            this.IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.2");
            this.sendData = new byte[1024];

    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

        public void mouse(int x, int y) {

            try {

                  String sentence = "{" + x + "," + y + "}";
                  this.sendData = sentence.getBytes();
                  DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(this.sendData, this.sendData.length, this.IPAddress, 9871);
                  this.clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

python udp serv:

```
import socket

PORT = 9871
IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((IP, PORT))
print "Server %s" % IP

while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
        if data:
            print "received message:", data
        else:
            print "dead"
```

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a stream protocol. That means that when you `send()` (or in your case `.writeBytes()`) multiple times, no boundaries between the arguments to the different calls are preserved.

E.g., when you send:

```
send("1,2");
send("-3,4");
send("5,6");
send("-7,8");
```

Then this could arrive on the other end as:

```
"1,2-3,45,6-7,8"
```

If you want to use TCP and preserve boundaries between messages, you need to add a layer to your protocol to provide this. There are two traditional ways to achieve this:

- Use a separator byte which marks the end of a message. Make sure a valid message will never contain the separator byte.
- Prepend each message with a fixed-length length field, e.g. a 32-bit integer.

In your case, taking the first option by simply adding newlines might do the trick:

```
send("1,2\n");
send("-3,4\n");
send("5,6\n");
send("-7,8\n");
```

This will arrive on the other end as something like:

```
"1,2\n-3,4\n5,6\n-7,8"
```

When you read, you can then use the newline characters to reconstruct the original messages.

Be wary of incomplete lines. We were simplifying a little bit above when we said the data would necessarily arrive as `"1,2\n-3,4\n5,6\n-7,8"`. It could also arrive a little bit at a time:

```
"1,2\n-3," // from the first read call
"4\n5,6\n-7,8" // from the second read call
```

When you read messages from a TCP stream, you need to put what you read into a buffer. You can't discard data until you have processed a whole message (or until something leads you to want to give up on the connection entirely). For instance, if the buffer ends with the incomplete message `"-3,"`, then you need to read until you have the rest of the message: `"4\n"`.

Another solution which may be appropriate is to using a datagram protocol such as UDP, where a message on the sender's side really does correspond to a message on the receiver's side. (Note that there are also other very significant differences between TCP and UDP! Don't switch over based on this alone.)

Comment: I've tried to change my code to use UDP because it did seem way more logical to be using in this scenario but I did encounter another weird problem, I've implemented the new code into python and the android app and it works perfectly (the data sending) but only on the simulator, when I try from my device it just crashes.. (I've added the new code to my post)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was, that you do not flush the stream after you called

```
this.outToServer.writeBytes(""+x+","+y);
```

If you will call

```
out.flush();
```

afterwards, the data will be send (descriptor will be flushed) immediately.

I think issue number two should be a result of issue number one.
Beside that you should really consider using an adequate protocol.

Comment: Tried to change to UDP and it works perfectly except only on my simulator, when I try to run the code on my device it crashes (updated code in post)

Answer (score 0):

You have two major issues in your implementation.

1. Firstly the data is sent outgoing without buffering on a stream meaning that there is no way for the receiving end to now when a sending of coordinates starts or ends.

   You should add buffering to the output stream with a flush after a package is finished. This will give the best behaviour on the receiving side. When sending text it is also recomendable to use a Writer when adding the text to the stream. But foremost you need a way to packet all the outgoing info for one mouse update (e.g. add a prefix and suffix character like {x,y}).
2. Your second problem is that you do not use onInterceptTouchEvent (returning true when interxepting the move) to get exclusive rights to the move data before starting to monitor the onTouchData(). I would recommend checking that there has been a move of at least

   ```
   ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop
   ```

   before intercepting the move. This will avoid you getting small shakes/stirring on the mouse cursor. And you can avoid other apps from interferring with strike detection and the like. When you get the down message you may temporarily save the start value to use after intercept for delta calculations.